# How to write multiple CSVs with each unique filter

Tags: r, dataframe

Hi I have the following dataframe

```
df = data.frame(Country = c("Japan", "Japan", "Thailand", "Germany", "Thailand"), 
                            Count = c(15, 5, 25, 5, 60))

splitdf = split(df, df$Country)
```

There are 3 countries; Japan, Thailand and Germany. I have put them into a list and I want it to be written it into a CSV and their names should be their respective country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#Code
mapply(write.csv,splitdf,file=paste0(names(splitdf),'.csv'))
```

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply, I tried running to code and it returned me this 

$Germany
NULL

$Japan
NULL

$Thailand
NULL

Comment: @realbeast91 Yeah that is only the output that means that files have been created. Go to your directory and files in csv must be created!

Comment: Hi thanks! This works tremendously. Sorry for the late reply, I have been real busy at work.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `imap` from `purrr` :

```
purrr::imap(splitdf, ~write.csv(.x, paste0(.y, '.csv'), row.names = FALSE))
```

Or `Map` in base R :

```
Map(function(x, y) write.csv(x, paste0(y, '.csv'), row.names = FALSE), 
                   splitdf, names(splitdf))
```